# calculating calendar week php

Tags: php, date

If anyone has an idea how can I calculate a calendar week depending on given date in php, for example 06.06.2013 (format like this 2013-06-06). is calendar week 23. I was searching for the solution all morning and found nothing useful. Any help or link, anything would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I searched for 10 seconds: http://www.google.com.au/#gs_rn=16&gs_ri=psy-ab&suggest=p&cp=17&gs_id=1y&xhr=t&q=php+week+number+from+date&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=php+week+number+f&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.dGI&fp=41087a23cf8457bf&biw=1440&bih=809

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`date("W")`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date("W", strtotime('2013-06-06'));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oUYmsQ)

Answer (score 8):

`date('W')` should give you the week of the year. **RTM**

If you don't have your time as a unix timestamp you can use `strtotime()` first and pass it as the second parameter

ex. `date('W',strtotime($my_time_string))`

[You can see the PHP manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: +1 For the same reason as @MaximKumpan

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$time = '2013-06-06';
$calendar_week = date('W', strtotime($time));
```